# Why does simplejson work in Terminal and not TextMate?

Tags: python, textmate, simplejson

I'm using simplejson to get data from the New York Time API. It works when I run the file through the terminal with the command "python test.py" but not when I run through TextMate using command + R. I'm running the exact same file. Why is this?

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.4, TextMate 1.5.10, and Python 2.6.4.

Edit: Sorry for forgetting to include this: by "doesn't work," I mean it says "No module named simplejson". I also noticed that this happens for PyMongo as well ("No module named pymongo").

Comment: simplejson handles JSON, not data getting.

Comment: Try running this script in both textmate and terminal:  `import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)` and add that output to your question; that'll tell us which path is missing.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work? You should provide more information like error messages and what-not. However, I assume that the version of python is different, and simplejson isn't on your PYTHONPATH when launched from textmate.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, `simplejson` was incorporated into the Python 2.6 distribution's standard library as `json`. So if you don't feel like wrestling with the import problem, try simply  changing all your references to `simplejson` to `json` instead.

But, as suggested, this is going to turn out to be a PythonPath issue. Run these lines in the Python interpreter and from TextMate and compare the results.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

To find out where simplejson is installed (if you don't know), do this in the Python interpreter:

```
import simplejson
print simplejson.__file__
```

If you want/need to set PYTHONPATH manually for TextMate, you can do that by adding it under Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables.